# Getting the following error: Error in chrome_ver(chromecheck[["platform"]], chromever) :

Tags: r, selenium-chromedriver, rselenium

I am trying to use RSelenium to open up a webpage but I keep running into the same error.

```
  version requested doesnt match versions available = 94.0.4606.113,95.0.4638.69,96.0.4664.35,96.0.4664.45
```

My code:

```
   eCaps <- list(
      chromeOptions =
        list(prefs = list(
          "download.default_directory" = dl_dir
        )
        )
    )

    rD <- rsDriver(chromever = '96.0.4664.45',
                   browser = "chrome",
                   port = 4568L,
                   verbose = F,
                   extraCapabilities = eCaps)
    
    
    remDr <- rD[["client"]]
```

If I go to my chrome browser the version I find is 96.0.4664.45. I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the error wrong? I'm pretty new to programming so any advice would be incredibly helpful thanks!

Comment: Have you updated chrome? Else you may use any version provided in the error?

Comment: I was able to update chrome and it’s one of the versions stated in the error. I also tried changing my version in the code to the ones the error offered.